# How to call this set?

Tags: vector-spaces

Say $I=(x_1,x_2,x_3, ..., x_n)$ where $0 \le x_i \le 1$. Then all $I$ shall forms a set.

Question is, does this kind of set have a specific name? or How will you call it with respect to the constraint  $0 \le x_i \le 1$?

Than you.

Comment: That set is not a vector space in any sensible way.

Comment: OK. Let's say it is set.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of $\mathbb{R}^{n}/\mathbb{Z}^{n}$?

Comment: Your set is the so called *$n$-dimensional cube* $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: $n$-dimensional cube it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product): $$I=[0,1]^n=\underbrace{[0,1]\times[0,1]\times\cdots\times[0,1]}_{\displaystyle n~\text{times}}$$ often called [$n$-dimensional cube or hypercube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube).

Comment: The edited version of question does not claim that $I$ is a vector space.

Comment: @user2097 I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, I changed the vector space to simply set.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ and $Q$ are sets then the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) $P \times Q$ is defined to be the set of all ordered pairs $(p,q)$ where $p$ belongs to $P$ and $q$ belongs to $Q$. In symbols:
$$P \times Q := \{ (p,q) : p \in P, q \in Q \}$$

This operation is distributive, i.e. $(P \times Q) \times R = P \times (Q \times R)$.

In your case, each of the $x_i$ lie between $0$ and $1$ we have $x_i \in [0,1]$. We have
$$[0,1]^n = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) : 0 \le x_i \le 1\}$$

The power notation is borrowed from ordinary multiplication. Just as $a \times a \times a = a^3$, we can use $$[0,1] \times [0,1] \times [0,1] = [0,1]^3$$

This notation is the same with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}^3$, which are the sets of ordered pairs of real numbers and ordered triples of complex numbers respectively.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the patience.

Comment: @Lansiz If you found my answer helpful then you might consider up-voting it by clicking the up-arrow. You should up-vote answers that you find useful.

Comment: Sure, @FlybyNight